# Save a string of text, if its proceeded by a different specific string of text?

Tags: python, python-3.x, fastq

Sorry about the poor title, I don't know how else to word my question.

I've written a script which pulls out data from fastq files (plain text genomic read files). Every 1st line is a header, 2nd line is a base string - the 3rd and 4th lines aren't needed.

```
filename = 'C0_GGCTAC_R1_no_adapter_trimming.fastq'
new_filename = filename[:-9] + '_new.fastq'

with open(filename) as f_obj:
    file_contents = f_obj.readlines()

extracted_lines = ''
line_count = 0

# Pull header and base lines
for line in file_contents:
    line_count += 1
    # Headers
    if line_count == 1:
        extracted_lines += line
    # Reads ending in A
    elif line_count == 2 and line[-2] == 'A':
        extracted_lines += line
    # Reads ending in G
    elif line_count == 2 and line[-2] == 'G':
        extracted_lines += line
    # Reset counter
    elif line_count == 4:
        line_count = 0

with open(new_filename, 'w') as f_obj:
    f_obj.write(extracted_lines)
print(new_filename + " was created.")
```

The script pulls the header of each read, and the string of bases in the read, as long as the read of bases ends in an A or a G. 
A sample of the input file would be:

```
@HWI-D00461:137:C9H2FACXX:3:1101:1239:1968 1:N:0:GGCTAC
NTGTGTAATAGATTTTACTTTTGCCTTTAAGCCCAAGGTCCTGGACTTGAAACATCCAAGGGATGGAAAATGCCGTATAACAGGGTGGAAGAGAGATTTGA
+
#1=BDDFFHHHFHIJJJJJJJJJJJJJJJJJJJJJIJJIJJJJJHJIIJHGIJJJJJJIHJJBGHJHIIJJJHHHHFFFFEEEDD;?BACDDDA?@CDDDC
@HWI-D00461:137:C9H2FACXX:3:1101:1117:1968 1:N:0:GGCTAC
NAAAGTCTACCAATTATACTTAGTGTGAAGAGGTGGGAGTTAAATATGACTTCCATTAATAGTTTCATTGTTTGGAAAACAGAGGTAATTTTTGATACAGA
+
#1=DDDFDFHHHGHIIGJJJJHIJIHHDIHHIJGGEI@GFGHIHIJHEFHIIIIGIJGHHGECFGIDHGIHIIEGIIJHHEEFFF7?ACEECCBBDEDDDC
```

The output file looks like this.

```
@HWI-D00461:137:C9H2FACXX:3:1101:1117:1968 1:N:0:GGCTAC
NAAAGTCTACCAATTATACTTAGTGTGAAGAGGTGGGAGTTAAATATGACTTCCATTAATAGTTTCATTGTTTGGAAAACAGAGGTAATTTTTGATACAGA
@HWI-D00461:137:C9H2FACXX:3:1101:1200:1972 1:N:0:GGCTAC
@HWI-D00461:137:C9H2FACXX:3:1101:1087:1973 1:N:0:GGCTAC
NTAATCCAACTAACTAAAAATAAAAAGATTCAAATAGGTACAGAAAACAATGAAGGTGTAGAGGTGAGAAATCAACAGGATGTTCAGAAGCCTGTGTATGA
```

Although this contains all the data a need, it pulls out every single header line (begins with '@'), which is unnecessary.

How can I modify my code to only pull out the header line, if it is proceeded by a string of bases that end in A or G?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that you are adding the *id* to for every record, not only for the ones you are interested in. A quick solution would be to keep the *id* in a variable and only add it when it is necessary:

```
filename = 'C0_GGCTAC_R1_no_adapter_trimming.fastq'
new_filename = filename[:-9] + '_new.fastq'

with open(filename) as f_obj:
    file_contents = f_obj.readlines()

extracted_lines = ''
line_count = 0

# Pull header and base lines
for line in file_contents:
    line_count += 1
    # Headers
    if line_count == 1:
        id_string = line
    # Reads ending in A
    elif line_count == 2 and line[-2] == 'A':
        extracted_lines += id_string
        extracted_lines += line
    # Reads ending in G
    elif line_count == 2 and line[-2] == 'G':
        extracted_lines += id_string
        extracted_lines += line
    # Reset counter
    elif line_count == 4:
        line_count = 0

with open(new_filename, 'w') as f_obj:
    f_obj.write(extracted_lines)
print(new_filename + " was created.")
```

I also have to say that that code is not much efficient, specially in terms of memory usage: you are reading a (usually) very big file into memory, but you only need a single record at a time.

Secondary issues are that your conditions can be compacted and that you can work with modulos to know in which line type you are:

```
filename = 'C0_GGCTAC_R1_no_adapter_trimming.fastq'
new_filename = filename[:-9] + '_new.fastq'

with open(filename) as in_f_obj, open(new_filename, 'w') as out_f_obj:
    # Process the file
    line_count = 0
    for line in in_f_obj:
        line_count += 1

        # Extract the information for each record
        if line_count % 4 == 1:
            id_string = line
        elif line_count % 4 == 2:
            seq = line
        elif line_count % 4 == 3:
            extra = line
        elif line_count % 4 == 4:
            # Last part of the record. Here we have all the information
            # and we can decide if we want to output something
            # and what we want to output
            qual = line
            if seq[-2] == 'A' or seq[-2] == 'G'
                out_f_obj.write(id_string)
                out_f_obj.write(seq)

print(new_filename + " was created.")
```

In this code, you only keep a single record in memory. The `line_count` variable contains the real number of lines processed and you have all the data from the input, so you can alter the output afterwards quite easily.

I would add an extra detail, I would strip the newline in each read line and add it if needed when writing:

```
# Extract the information for each record
if line_count % 4 == 1:
    id_string = line.rstrip()
elif line_count % 4 == 2:
    seq = line.rstrip()
elif line_count % 4 == 3:
    extra = line.rstrip()
elif line_count % 4 == 4:
    # Last part of the record. Here we have all the information
    # and we can decide if we want to output something
    # and what we want to output
    qual = line.rstrip()
    if seq[-1] == 'A' or seq[-1] == 'G'
        out_f_obj.write("{}\n{}\n".format(id_string, seq))
```

In that way, your data is clean, with no new-line formatting from the input file.

Comment: This was a major help, thank you! :)
Just a couple of things, using youre code I still had a problem where unnecessary headers where being written, so at the end of each elif loop where the header was written, I cleared the variable. This gave me my desired output. 

My code runs much faster after removing the file_contents variable too!

Comment: Unnecessary headers still around? That does not make sense, just look at the code: every time a header is added, the corresponding sequence is also added. There is no space for lone headers :-?

Answer (score 0):

I think it would make your task easier to walk through the file in  4 line steps instead of single lines. At least assuming there are really always constantly 4 lines that belong to each other. Then you can filter the wanted bases before you append the according header line, for example like this:

```
extracted_lines = []
for i in range(0, len(file_contents), 4):
    header, bases, comment1, comment2 = file_contents[i:i+4]
    if bases[-1] in ["A", "G"]:
        extracted_lines.append(header)
        extracted_lines.append(bases)
```